# Why doesn't ServiceStack always link UserAuth and UserAuthDetails?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, servicestack, openid

I am struggling with something that I would have thought ServiceStack would do "out of the box"...

I have a ServiceStack API that allows authentication via credentials, basic, google OpenId and LinkedIn OAuth2.

Starting with empty UserAuth and UserAuthDetails table I have found that if I:

1. start my app and use credentials to log in
2. log out
3. log in using Google OpenId auth

ServiceStack creates two separate UserAuth records rather than linking the Google UserAuthDetail with the Credential authenticated UserAuth.  This is despite the two credentials showing the same email address in both records.

**BUT...**
If I start from a blank database and repeat the steps using the LinkedIn OAuth2 I find that a single UserAuth record is created with a linked UserAuthDetails record.  This is what I want the Google Auth to do.

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening and what I must do to ensure the Google Auth doesn't create a new UserAuth if there is already one with a matching email address?

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack merges User Auth details for the current authenticated [user session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions). i.e. not on any matching value returned by the OpenId/OAuth providers.

If you log out, then you end the current users session and authenticating again will behave as if it were a new browser session.

Comment: OK, thanks.  That doesn't explain the difference in functionality - when I repeat the steps with LinkedIn auth it doesn't behave this way.  It behaves the way I would expect it to...  If I log out from a credentials auth session and then log in using LinkedIn auth it doesn't create a second UserAuth record and when it creates the UserAuthDetails record it re-uses the UserAuthId from the previous credentials auth session.  I'd like the Google OpenId Auth to work the same way.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to downvote!  Can't undo it either?

Comment: Just realised I can undo the vote down when the answer is updated - @mythz - is this likely to be a bug - should I be doing a pull request?

Comment: Is there somewhere else I should be asking these questions?  I am a paid ServiceStack licensee and love the software - I could just do with some guidance on this issue.

Comment: @Drammy the customer support options are listed on https://servicestack.net/account/support - if this is a reproducible issue can you create an issue on https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues and list the steps to repro it so we can track it. Can you also make sure that you clear the browser cookies before comparing the behavior of each, thx.